# supportsRtl is always false

Tags: android

supportsRtl is always false no matter I did, here mine:

```
   <application
    android:name="********"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

and

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
.
.
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ".*****"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionName computeVersionName()
    versionCode computeVersionCode()
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {

        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"

    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

I read the value from here (I set android:layoutDirection="rtl" on all layouts but no effect, so I went to see the actual value in the runtime from this)

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Printer mPrinter = new StringBuilderPrinter(sb);
    getContext().getApplicationInfo().dump(mPrinter, "ssaa");

    String reportInfo = mPrinter.toString();
```

and the result:

```
ssaa packageName=*****
ssaa labelRes=0x7f070167 nonLocalizedLabel=null icon=0x7f02011d banner=0x0
ssaa className=*****
ssaa processName=****
ssaa taskAffinity=*****
ssaa uid=10187 flags=0x2 theme=0x7f09009a
ssaa requiresSmallestWidthDp=0 compatibleWidthLimitDp=0 largestWidthLimitDp=0
ssaa sourceDir=/data/app/*****-1/base.apk
ssaa seinfo=default
ssaa agentType=1
ssaa allowedAgentType=1
ssaa category=1023
ssaa allowCategory=0,701-1023
ssaa bbccategory=1023
ssaa allowCategory=0,701-1023
ssaa accessInfo=0
ssaa dataDir=/data/data/********
ssaa enabled=true targetSdkVersion=24 versionCode=19111
ssaa supportsRtl=false
```

I have tried to set the flags by my self but also no use (from getApplicationInfo().flags)

I have android studio 2.2 preview 6

PS: I cleaned the project but no use, restart the whole mac but no use

PS: the device language is Arabic, Hebrew tried them bu no effect

PS: I added this android:layoutDirection="rtl" to make sure it's working but no effect

Comment: go to developer options on your device and check Force RTL layout direction

Comment: I tried this, stills the same